# Advice needed- aweber form submission using curl?

Tags: forms, curl, submission

Advice needed for backend form submission to aweber and get response.

Scenario

When customer signup at my form, I will 
1. insert the customer details into my own database, 
2. send them a welcome email from my system, 
3. at the same time I want the email to be added into aweber (this should run in the background, so that customer no need to fill in details for second time)

If I use the php curl call alone, is it a good solution?

I want to submit form value to aweber, so that aweber add the new email into their system, and then response to my backend script?

I have seen many versions outside, which may include:

http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/

http://freshmeat.net/projects/curl_http_client/

http://snoopy.sourceforge.net/

Are they having any special benefit over the normal php curl call to pass in data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this successfully before just using just a cURL request, but I couldn't get aweber to accept the submission without sending the person a confirmation message of their own.  Basically it acts as if you have "confirmed opt-in" turned on, even if you turn it off.

Also, aweber addlead.pl script doesn't return anything, so if you had something in mind for that it won't go anywhere.

Hope this helps!